# There was an error while trying to load the gem 'ie_iframe_cookies'. (Bundler::GemRequireError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

After update to rails 5.1, on running server locally, It gives an error mentioned below, I checked everywhere but I didn't find any solution. I also removed before filter from all over the code but still, it gives this error.

```
Gem Load Error is: undefined method `before_filter' for ActionController::Base:Class
Did you mean?  before_action
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/ie_iframe_cookies-0.2.0/lib/ie_iframe_cookies.rb:5:in `<class:Base>'
/home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/ie_iframe_cookies-0.2.0/lib/ie_iframe_cookies.rb:4:in `<module:ActionController>'
/home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/ie_iframe_cookies-0.2.0/lib/ie_iframe_cookies.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
/home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
/home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
/home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
/home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
/home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require'
/home/affi/officeData/evercam-devops/evercam-dashboard/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
/home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:128:in `require'
/home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:128:in `block in perform'
/home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:125:in `tap'
/home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:125:in `perform'
/home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
/home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
/home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
/home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
/home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties- 5.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:8:in `require'
bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
  from /home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler- 1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:90:in `block (2 levels) in require'
  from /home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
  from /home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
  from /home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
  from /home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
  from /home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/bundler-1.14.6/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `require'
  from /home/affi/officeData/evercam-devops/evercam-dashboard/config/application.rb:12:in `<top (required)>'
  from /home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:128:in `require'
  from /home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:128:in `block in perform'
  from /home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:125:in `tap'
  from /home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:125:in `perform'
  from /home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
  from /home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
  from /home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/thor-0.19.4/lib/thor.rb:369:in `dispatch'
  from /home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
  from /home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
  from /home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/railties-5.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
  from bin/rails:8:in `require'
  from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Here is my gem file, 'Bundle Install' is running fine.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.3.1'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1'

gem 'railties', '~> 5.1'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'yui-compressor'
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'javascript-securehash-rails'
gem 'fog'
gem 'asset_sync'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
gem 'stripe',
  github: 'stripe/stripe-ruby'
gem 'stripe_event'
gem 'nprogress-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'georuby'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'hashie'
gem 'timezone'

gem 'pg'
gem 'sequel'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.10'
gem 'protected_attributes_continued'
gem 'rack-rewrite'
gem 'typhoeus'
gem 'puma'
gem 'data_uri'
gem 'country_select',
  github: 'stefanpenner/country_select'
gem "devise",
  git: 'https://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git'
gem 'ie_iframe_cookies'
gem 'heroku-api'
gem 'intercom-rails'
gem 'wicked_pdf'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'
gem 'intercom', require: 'intercom'
gem 'imgareaselect-rails', '~> 1.0'
gem 'dotenv'

group :evercam do
  gem 'evercam',
    github: 'evercam/evercam-ruby'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
  gem 'newrelic_rpm'
  gem 'wkhtmltopdf-heroku'
  gem 'heroku-deflater',
    git: "https://github.com/romanbsd/heroku-deflater.git"
end

group :development do
  # gem 'jazz_hands',
  #   github: 'nixme/jazz_hands',
  #   branch: 'bring-your-own-debugger'
  gem 'pry-byebug'
  gem 'rspec'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
end

group :test do
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl'
  gem 'vcr'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'webmock'
  gem 'poltergeist'
  gem 'nokogiri'
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'rack_session_access'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'launchy'
  gem 'codeclimate-test-reporter', require: nil
end

source 'https://rails-assets.org' do
  gem 'rails-assets-bootbox'
  gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap'
  gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap-datepicker'
  gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap-tabdrop'
  gem 'rails-assets-datatables'
  gem 'rails-assets-datatables-plugins'
  gem 'rails-assets-datetimepicker'
  gem 'rails-assets-fullcalendar'
  gem 'rails-assets-iCheck'
  gem 'rails-assets-jquery-cookie'
  gem 'rails-assets-moment', '~> 2.12.0'
  gem 'rails-assets-jquery-form-validator'
  gem 'rails-assets-jquery.browser'
  gem 'rails-assets-jquery.nicescroll'
  gem 'rails-assets-jquery.slimscroll'
  gem 'rails-assets-jquery.uniform'
  gem 'rails-assets-ladda'
  gem 'rails-assets-screenfull'
  gem 'rails-assets-videojs'
  gem 'rails-assets-bs-slider'
  gem 'rails-assets-bootstrap-toggle'
  gem 'rails-assets-select2'
  gem 'rails-assets-jquery-tags-input'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is `before_filter` issue, `before_filter` has been removed in rails 5.1

You should use `before_action` instead of `before_filter`

Comment: I already did that, but still, it shows this `before_action` error.

Comment: Affi, did you replace them on the gem?

Comment: I think this is not dependent to the gem. can you paste your code how to use

Comment: No, I replaced this from my code, not from the gem.

Comment: please open this file /home/affi/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/ie_iframe_cookies-0.2.0/lib/ie_iframe_cookies.rb: and check where   `before_filter` is used and replace with the before_action

Comment: Sunny, editing the gem directly is not a good idea. I might work, but it will still break in other machines or in production.

Comment: Yes I know that but i want to first check after that i will tell him to fork the gem

Answer (score 0):

`before_filter` is deprecated and won't work in rails 5. Also, it looks like the gem is also "deprecated/unmaintained". You can try forking the repo and changing all `before_filter` to `before_action`. Then add the repo to your gemfile instead; but, there are no guarantees that will work.

Comment: I have posted same answer

Comment: Sunny, I believe you failed to realize that the problem is with the gem. My answer addresses that.